# When i press register button on my html page , my PHP page does not load

Tags: php, html, database, xampp, backend

```
<?php

$username = $_POST['username'];
$email = $_POST['email'];
$password = $_POST['password'];

var_dump($username, $email, $password);
```

```
<div class="form-box">
            <div class="button-box">
                <div id="btn"></div>
                <button class="toggle-btn" onclick="login()">Login</button>
                <button class="toggle-btn" onclick="register()">Register</button>
            </div>
            <form id="login" class="input-group">
                <input type="text" class="input-field" placeholder="username" required>
                <input type="password" class="input-field" placeholder="password" required>
                <input type="checkbox" class="checkbox"><span>Remember Password?</span>
                <button type="submit" class="submit-btn"  id="login-btn">Login</button>
            </form>
            <form id="register" class="input-group" action="register.php" method="post">
                <input type="text" name="username" class="input-field" placeholder="Username" required>
                <input type="email" name="email" class="input-field" placeholder="Email" required>
                <input type="password" name="password" class="input-field" placeholder="Password" required>
                <input type="checkbox" class="checkbox"><span>I agree to the terms & conditions</span>
                <button type="submit" class="submit-btn" id="register-btn">Register</button>
            </form>            
        </div>
```

and this is the error i got in the console

```
arning: Undefined array key "username" in D:\Education\ComputerScience\HTML,CSS,JAVASCRIPT\Slot Machine\register.php on line 3
PHP Warning:  Undefined array key "username" in D:\Education\ComputerScience\HTML,CSS,JAVASCRIPT\Slot Machine\register.php on line 3
PHP Warning:  Undefined array key "email" in D:\Education\ComputerScience\HTML,CSS,JAVASCRIPT\Slot Machine\register.php on line 4
PHP Warning:  Undefined array key "password" in D:\Education\ComputerScience\HTML,CSS,JAVASCRIPT\Slot Machine\register.php on line 5

Warning: Undefined array key "email" in D:\Education\ComputerScience\HTML,CSS,JAVASCRIPT\Slot Machine\register.php on line 4

Warning: Undefined array key "password" in D:\Education\ComputerScience\HTML,CSS,JAVASCRIPT\Slot Machine\register.php on line 5
NULL
NULL
NULL
```

I just tried changing up my php code to some i found on youtube, i asked chat GPT but it said that there's nothing wrong with my code.

Comment: in the network tab i get '405 method not allowed'

Comment: 405 error is usually when you are not using a webserver which supports POST requests, and maybe doesn't support php. But you got those undefined array key errors suggesting the php was executed when the page loaded (which of course was a GET and the errors are because there was no form data to read, and your code doesn't check if the form was actually submitted before trying to process the form fields)

Answer (score 0):

```
// Ensure that, form is submitted.
if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] === 'POST') {
    // Fetch all the necessary variables.
    $username = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'username');
    $email = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'email', FILTER_SANITIZE_EMAIL);
    $password = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'password');

    // Does form contain all necessary variables?
    if (isset($username, $email, $password)) {
        // Handle them.
        // var_dump($username, $email, $password);
    }
}
```